# my SVG chess images are not changing their color

Tags: javascript

I am building a chess game in my js/css part of code when i try to change my svg images they're not working idk why, I used fill in my css on that very element which is a child, but nothing is wrong

here is my code

```js
const
  gameBoard     = document.querySelector("#gameboard")
, playerDispaly = document.querySelector("#player")
, infoDisplay   = document.querySelector("#info-display")
, width         = 8
, startPieces = 
  [ rook, knight, bishop, queen, king, bishop, knight, rook
  , pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn
  , "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
  , "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
  , pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn, pawn
  , rook, knight, bishop, queen, king, bishop, knight, rook, ] 
  ;
createBoard();

function createBoard() {
  startPieces.forEach((startPieces, i) => {
    const square = document.createElement("div");
    square.classList.add("square");
    //square.classList.add("beige")//
    const row = Math.floor((63 - i) / 8) + 1;
    if (row % 2 === 0) {
      square.classList.add(i % 2 === 0 ? "beige" : "brown");
    } else {
      square.classList.add(i % 2 === 0 ? "brown" : "beige");
    }

    /*if (i <= 15) {
      square.firstChild.firstChild.classList.add("black");
    }*/

    square.innerHTML = startPieces;
    square.setAttribute("sqaure-id", i);
    gameBoard.append(square);
  });
}
```

```css
#gameboard {
  width            : 320px;
  height           : 320px;
  background-color : black;
  display          : flex;
  flex-wrap        : wrap;
  }
.square {
  height           : 40px;
  width            : 40px;
  }
.square svg {
  height           : 30px;
  width            : 30px;
  margin           : 5px;
  }
.beige {
  background-color : rgb(110, 110, 98);
  }
.brown {
  background-color : rgb(169, 43, 43);
  }
.black {
  fill             : #ff0000;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Chess</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gameboard"></div>
  <p>It is <span id="player"></span>go.</p>
  <p id="info-display"></p>

  <!-- actual assets missing here -->
  <script src="pieces.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

the issue is with the svg fill property not working, or my css idk i tried different things like making my sqaure svg  fill to inherit but didn't work so idk

```js
const king =
  '<div class="piece" id="king" ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M224 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32V48h16c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32H256v48H408c22.1 0 40 17.9 40 40c0 5.3-1 10.5-3.1 15.4L368 400H80L3.1 215.4C1 210.5 0 205.3 0 200c0-22.1 17.9-40 40-40H192V112H176c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32h16V32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM38.6 473.4L80 432H368l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H54.6C42.1 512 32 501.9 32 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16z"/></svg></div>';
const queen =
  '<div class="piece" id="queen" ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M256 0a56 56 0 1 1 0 112A56 56 0 1 1 256 0zM134.1 143.8c3.3-13 15-23.8 30.2-23.8c12.3 0 22.6 7.2 27.7 17c12 23.2 36.2 39 64 39s52-15.8 64-39c5.1-9.8 15.4-17 27.7-17c15.3 0 27 10.8 30.2 23.8c7 27.8 32.2 48.3 62.1 48.3c10.8 0 21-2.7 29.8-7.4c8.4-4.4 18.9-4.5 27.6 .9c13 8 17.1 25 9.2 38L399.7 400H384 343.6 168.4 128 112.3L5.4 223.6c-7.9-13-3.8-30 9.2-38c8.7-5.3 19.2-5.3 27.6-.9c8.9 4.7 19 7.4 29.8 7.4c29.9 0 55.1-20.5 62.1-48.3zM256 224l0 0 0 0h0zM112 432H400l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H86.6C74.1 512 64 501.9 64 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16L112 432z"/></svg></div>';
const rook =
  '<div class="piece" id="rook" ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M32 192V48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h64c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16V88c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h32c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h64c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16V88c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h32c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h64c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16V192c0 10.1-4.7 19.6-12.8 25.6L352 256l16 144H80L96 256 44.8 217.6C36.7 211.6 32 202.1 32 192zm176 96h32c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V224c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32v48c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16zM22.6 473.4L64 432H384l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H38.6C26.1 512 16 501.9 16 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16z"/></svg></div>';
const bishop =
  '<div class="piece" id="bishop" ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M128 0C110.3 0 96 14.3 96 32c0 16.1 11.9 29.4 27.4 31.7C78.4 106.8 8 190 8 288c0 47.4 30.8 72.3 56 84.7V400H256V372.7c25.2-12.5 56-37.4 56-84.7c0-37.3-10.2-72.4-25.3-104.1l-99.4 99.4c-6.2 6.2-16.4 6.2-22.6 0s-6.2-16.4 0-22.6L270.8 154.6c-23.2-38.1-51.8-69.5-74.2-90.9C212.1 61.4 224 48.1 224 32c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32H128zM48 432L6.6 473.4c-4.2 4.2-6.6 10-6.6 16C0 501.9 10.1 512 22.6 512H297.4c12.5 0 22.6-10.1 22.6-22.6c0-6-2.4-11.8-6.6-16L272 432H48z"/></svg></div>';
const pawn =
  '<div class="piece" id="pawn"  > <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M215.5 224c29.2-18.4 48.5-50.9 48.5-88c0-57.4-46.6-104-104-104S56 78.6 56 136c0 37.1 19.4 69.6 48.5 88H96c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32c0 16.5 12.5 30 28.5 31.8L80 400H240L227.5 287.8c16-1.8 28.5-15.3 28.5-31.8c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32h-8.5zM22.6 473.4c-4.2 4.2-6.6 10-6.6 16C16 501.9 26.1 512 38.6 512H281.4c12.5 0 22.6-10.1 22.6-22.6c0-6-2.4-11.8-6.6-16L256 432H64L22.6 473.4z"/></svg></div>';
const knight =
  '<div class="piece" id="knight" ><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M96 48L82.7 61.3C70.7 73.3 64 89.5 64 106.5V238.9c0 10.7 5.3 20.7 14.2 26.6l10.6 7c14.3 9.6 32.7 10.7 48.1 3l3.2-1.6c2.6-1.3 5-2.8 7.3-4.5l49.4-37c6.6-5 15.7-5 22.3 0c10.2 7.7 9.9 23.1-.7 30.3L90.4 350C73.9 361.3 64 380 64 400H384l28.9-159c2.1-11.3 3.1-22.8 3.1-34.3V192C416 86 330 0 224 0H83.8C72.9 0 64 8.9 64 19.8c0 7.5 4.2 14.3 10.9 17.7L96 48zm24 68a20 20 0 1 1 40 0 20 20 0 1 1 -40 0zM22.6 473.4c-4.2 4.2-6.6 10-6.6 16C16 501.9 26.1 512 38.6 512H409.4c12.5 0 22.6-10.1 22.6-22.6c0-6-2.4-11.8-6.6-16L384 432H64L22.6 473.4z"/></svg></div> ';
```

Comment: first of all the array startPieces is initialized with string literals that should be wrapped in quotes. Then: _i try to change my svg images_ .. no you aren't. Where?

Comment: there is no SVG here. You must read  [SO guideline**S**](https://stackoverflow.com/help) about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I edited your question and made the code as a live snippet. You can see the error thrown because of the missing quotes. Plus I highlighted the fact that the assets referenced in the html are missing here

Comment: *if* you had `const pawn = [svg for pawn]` (etc) then you wouldn't need the quotes in the array as it would then use the variable - the innerHTML would also use these consts.  But that's not in the code provided, so presents as an error.

Comment: hi sorry guys updated my code with the svg asset

Comment: The part that makes it black is commented (in the snippet)  `.square { fill: black }` should apply to your SVG, here's a cut down version showing it working:  https://jsfiddle.net/dg8ux4L5/  I'll also note that the *default* is black and running your code shows them all as black.

Comment: The commented code to set "black" runs before the square.innerHTML - so the .firstChild (etc) fails.   You also don't need .firstChild as `fill` inherits, so can add it directly to `square`

Comment: Updated code.  Default fill to white / add class to the square directly.   https://jsfiddle.net/dg8ux4L5/1/

Comment: thanks @freedomn-m that helped I wanna thank everyone else your input was appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

SVG elements use a specific syntax.
In your case use `fill` attribute.
can also work on CSS:

```css
.piece {
  width: 100px;
  }
.piece>svg {
  fill: orange;
  }
```

```html
<div class="piece" id="king"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M224 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32V48h16c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32H256v48H408c22.1 0 40 17.9 40 40c0 5.3-1 10.5-3.1 15.4L368 400H80L3.1 215.4C1 210.5 0 205.3 0 200c0-22.1 17.9-40 40-40H192V112H176c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32h16V32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM38.6 473.4L80 432H368l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H54.6C42.1 512 32 501.9 32 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16z"/></svg></div>
```

## Something more elaborate:

*I had to correct some imperfections in the SVG code, I also added a border to the pieces to improve their visual contrast*...

```js
const
  chessBoard = document.querySelector('#chess-board')
, htmlFrag   = htmlCod => new Range().createContextualFragment(htmlCod)
, pieces =  // see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)#Naming_the_pieces
    [ { typ:'king',   abr:'K', color:'white', pos:'e1' }, { typ:'queen',  abr:'Q', color:'white', pos:'d1' }
    , { typ:'rook',   abr:'R', color:'white', pos:'h1' }, { typ:'rook',   abr:'R', color:'white', pos:'a1' }
    , { typ:'bishop', abr:'B', color:'white', pos:'c1' }, { typ:'bishop', abr:'B', color:'white', pos:'f1' }
    , { typ:'knight', abr:'N', color:'white', pos:'b1' }, { typ:'knight', abr:'N', color:'white', pos:'g1' }
    , { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'white', pos:'a2' }, { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'white', pos:'e2' }
    , { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'white', pos:'b2' }, { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'white', pos:'f2' }
    , { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'white', pos:'c2' }, { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'white', pos:'g2' }
    , { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'white', pos:'d2' }, { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'white', pos:'h2' }
    , { typ:'king',   abr:'K', color:'black', pos:'e8' }, { typ:'queen',  abr:'Q', color:'black', pos:'d8' }
    , { typ:'rook',   abr:'R', color:'black', pos:'h8' }, { typ:'rook',   abr:'R', color:'black', pos:'a8' }
    , { typ:'bishop', abr:'B', color:'black', pos:'c8' }, { typ:'bishop', abr:'B', color:'black', pos:'f8' }
    , { typ:'knight', abr:'N', color:'black', pos:'b8' }, { typ:'knight', abr:'N', color:'black', pos:'g8' }
    , { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'black', pos:'a7' }, { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'black', pos:'e7' }
    , { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'black', pos:'b7' }, { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'black', pos:'f7' }
    , { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'black', pos:'c7' }, { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'black', pos:'g7' }
    , { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'black', pos:'d7' }, { typ:'pawn',   abr:'',  color:'black', pos:'h7' }
    ];  // also : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode

let sqColor = ['beige','brown'], iColor = 0;

for( let n=9;--n;)              // let's create chess bord  [beiges,brown] squares
for( let l of 'abcdefgh')
  {
  chessBoard.append(htmlFrag(`<div id="${l}${n}" class="${sqColor[1&(n + iColor++)]}"></div>`));
  }

let strokeColor; 
for( let {typ,color,pos } of pieces)          // set pieces on chess board :
  {
  strokeColor = (color==='white') ? 'black' : 'white';
  let piece = htmlFrag(`<svg fill="${color}" stroke="${strokeColor}"><use xlink:href="#${typ}"/></svg>`);
  chessBoard.querySelector(`#${pos}`).append(piece);
  }
function movPiece( mov )
  {
  let
    [pos1, pos2] = mov.split('-')
  , e_p1svg      = document.querySelector(`#${pos1} > svg`)
  , p2square     = document.querySelector(`#${pos2}`)
    ;
  p2square.append( e_p1svg );
  pieces.find(p=>p.pos===pos1).pos = pos2;
  }

document.querySelector('#firstMov').onclick = e => // -- sample code for mov  =  e2-e4
  {
  e.currentTarget.disabled = true;
  movPiece( 'e2-e4' );
  }
```

```css
body       { background-color : #87878a; }
.noDisplay { display          : none;    }

#chess-board {
  --square-size : 50px;
  margin        : 10px;
  display       : flex;
  flex-wrap     : wrap;
  width         : calc( var(--square-size) * 8 );
  height        : calc( var(--square-size) * 8 );
  }
#chess-board > div {
  width    : var(--square-size);
  height   : var(--square-size);
  position : relative;
  }
#chess-board > div > svg {
  position     : absolute;
  top          : 5%;
  left         : 5%;
  width        : 90%;
  height       : 90%;
  stroke-width : 8;
}
.beige { background-color : #eaead9; }
.brown { background-color : #5f3737; }
```

```html
<div id="chess-board"></div>

<button id="firstMov"> play first mov : e2-e4 </button>

<svg class="noDisplay">
  <symbol id="king" viewBox="-32 -6 524 524"><path d="M224 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32V48h16c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32H256v48H408c22.1 0 40 17.9 40 40 c0 5.3-1 10.5-3.1 15.4L368 400H80L3.1 215.4C1 210.5 0 205.3 0 200c0-22.1 17.9-40 40-40H192V112H176c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32h16V32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM38.6 473.4L80 432H368l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16 c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H54.6C42.1 512 32 501.9 32 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16z"/></symbol>
  <symbol id="queen" viewBox="-6 -6 524 524"><path d="M256 0a56 56 0 1 1 0 112A56 56 0 1 1 256 0zM134.1 143.8c3.3-13 15-23.8 30.2-23.8c12.3 0 22.6 7.2 27.7 17 c12 23.2 36.2 39 64 39s52-15.8 64-39c5.1-9.8 15.4-17 27.7-17c15.3 0 27 10.8 30.2 23.8c7 27.8 32.2 48.3 62.1 48.3 c10.8 0 21-2.7 29.8-7.4c8.4-4.4 18.9-4.5 27.6 .9c13 8 17.1 25 9.2 38L399.7 400H384 343.6 168.4 128 112.3L5.4 223.6 c-7.9-13-3.8-30 9.2-38c8.7-5.3 19.2-5.3 27.6-.9c8.9 4.7 19 7.4 29.8 7.4c29.9 0 55.1-20.5 62.1-48.3zM256 224l0 0 0 0h0z M112 432H400l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H86.6C74.1 512 64 501.9 64 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16L112 432z" /></symbol>
  <symbol id="rook" viewBox="-38 -6 524 524"><path d="M32 192V48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h64c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16V88c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h32c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h64 c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16V88c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h32c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h64c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16V192c0 10.1-4.7 19.6-12.8 25.6 L352 256l16 144H80L96 256 44.8 217.6C36.7 211.6 32 202.1 32 192zm176 96h32c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V224c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32 v48c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16zM22.6 473.4L64 432H384l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H38.6 C26.1 512 16 501.9 16 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16z" /></symbol>
  <symbol id="bishop" viewBox="-102 -6 524 524"><path d="M128 0C110.3 0 96 14.3 96 32c0 16.1 11.9 29.4 27.4 31.7C78.4 106.8 8 190 8 288c0 47.4 30.8 72.3 56 84.7V400H256V372.7 c25.2-12.5 56-37.4 56-84.7c0-37.3-10.2-72.4-25.3-104.1l-99.4 99.4c-6.2 6.2-16.4 6.2-22.6 0s-6.2-16.4 0-22.6L270.8 154.6 c-23.2-38.1-51.8-69.5-74.2-90.9C212.1 61.4 224 48.1 224 32c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32H128zM48 432L6.6 473.4c-4.2 4.2-6.6 10-6.6 16 C0 501.9 10.1 512 22.6 512H297.4c12.5 0 22.6-10.1 22.6-22.6c0-6-2.4-11.8-6.6-16L272 432H48z"/></symbol>
  <symbol id="pawn" viewBox="-102 -6 524 524"><path d="M215.5 224c29.2-18.4 48.5-50.9 48.5-88c0-57.4-46.6-104-104-104S56 78.6 56 136c0 37.1 19.4 69.6 48.5 88H96c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32 c0 16.5 12.5 30 28.5 31.8L80 400H240L227.5 287.8c16-1.8 28.5-15.3 28.5-31.8c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32h-8.5zM22.6 473.4c-4.2 4.2-6.6 10-6.6 16 C16 501.9 26.1 512 38.6 512H281.4c12.5 0 22.6-10.1 22.6-22.6c0-6-2.4-11.8-6.6-16L256 432H64L22.6 473.4z"/></symbol>
  <symbol id="knight" viewBox="-38 -6 524 524"><path d="M96 48L82.7 61.3C70.7 73.3 64 89.5 64 106.5V238.9c0 10.7 5.3 20.7 14.2 26.6l10.6 7c14.3 9.6 32.7 10.7 48.1 3l3.2-1.6 c2.6-1.3 5-2.8 7.3-4.5l49.4-37c6.6-5 15.7-5 22.3 0c10.2 7.7 9.9 23.1-.7 30.3L90.4 350C73.9 361.3 64 380 64 400H384l28.9-159 c2.1-11.3 3.1-22.8 3.1-34.3V192C416 86 330 0 224 0H83.8C72.9 0 64 8.9 64 19.8c0 7.5 4.2 14.3 10.9 17.7L96 48zm24 68 a20 20 0 1 1 40 0 20 20 0 1 1 -40 0zM22.6 473.4c-4.2 4.2-6.6 10-6.6 16C16 501.9 26.1 512 38.6 512H409.4 c12.5 0 22.6-10.1 22.6-22.6c0-6-2.4-11.8-6.6-16L384 432H64L22.6 473.4z"/></symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: FYI: OP is already using `fill:` (just trying to add to the wrong element (and default is black doesn't help)).  Your code works fine without needing to add to the `svg` as `fill` inherits: https://jsfiddle.net/z3md6ofu/

Comment: @freedomn-m added Something more elaborate in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your SVG string constants into functions that return a string containing data about the player.

```js
const renderKing = (color) => `
  <div class="piece" data-piece="king" data-color="${color}">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
      <path d="M224 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32V48h16c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32H256v48H408c22.1 0 40 17.9 40 40c0 5.3-1 10.5-3.1 15.4L368 400H80L3.1 215.4C1 210.5 0 205.3 0 200c0-22.1 17.9-40 40-40H192V112H176c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32h16V32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM38.6 473.4L80 432H368l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H54.6C42.1 512 32 501.9 32 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
`;
```

You can use HTML data attributes to achieve this. Now, your CSS styles are easier to work with.

```css
.piece[data-color="white"] > svg { fill: #fcc; }
.piece[data-color="black"] > svg { fill: #200; }
```

Also, you can simplify your tile color algorithm with div-mod (`/` `%`), to compute the row and column, and XOR (`^`) to compute the color:

```js
const row = Math.trunc(i / 8), col = i % 8;
square.classList.add((row ^ col) % 2 === 0 ? 'beige' : 'brown');
```

### Full example

```js
const gameBoard = document.querySelector("#gameboard");

const playerDispaly = document.querySelector("#player");
const infoDisplay = document.querySelector("#info-display");
const width = 8;

const renderKing = (color) => `
  <div class="piece" data-piece="king" data-color="${color}">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
      <path d="M224 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32V48h16c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32H256v48H408c22.1 0 40 17.9 40 40c0 5.3-1 10.5-3.1 15.4L368 400H80L3.1 215.4C1 210.5 0 205.3 0 200c0-22.1 17.9-40 40-40H192V112H176c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32h16V32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM38.6 473.4L80 432H368l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H54.6C42.1 512 32 501.9 32 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
`;
const renderQueen = (color) => `
  <div class="piece" data-piece="queen" data-color="${color}">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <path d="M256 0a56 56 0 1 1 0 112A56 56 0 1 1 256 0zM134.1 143.8c3.3-13 15-23.8 30.2-23.8c12.3 0 22.6 7.2 27.7 17c12 23.2 36.2 39 64 39s52-15.8 64-39c5.1-9.8 15.4-17 27.7-17c15.3 0 27 10.8 30.2 23.8c7 27.8 32.2 48.3 62.1 48.3c10.8 0 21-2.7 29.8-7.4c8.4-4.4 18.9-4.5 27.6 .9c13 8 17.1 25 9.2 38L399.7 400H384 343.6 168.4 128 112.3L5.4 223.6c-7.9-13-3.8-30 9.2-38c8.7-5.3 19.2-5.3 27.6-.9c8.9 4.7 19 7.4 29.8 7.4c29.9 0 55.1-20.5 62.1-48.3zM256 224l0 0 0 0h0zM112 432H400l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H86.6C74.1 512 64 501.9 64 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16L112 432z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
`;
const renderRook = (color) => `
  <div class="piece" data-piece="rook" data-color="${color}">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
    <path d="M32 192V48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h64c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16V88c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h32c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h64c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16V88c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h32c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h64c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16V192c0 10.1-4.7 19.6-12.8 25.6L352 256l16 144H80L96 256 44.8 217.6C36.7 211.6 32 202.1 32 192zm176 96h32c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V224c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32v48c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16zM22.6 473.4L64 432H384l41.4 41.4c4.2 4.2 6.6 10 6.6 16c0 12.5-10.1 22.6-22.6 22.6H38.6C26.1 512 16 501.9 16 489.4c0-6 2.4-11.8 6.6-16z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
 `;
const renderBishop = (color) => `
  <div class="piece" data-piece="bishop" data-color="${color}">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
      <path d="M128 0C110.3 0 96 14.3 96 32c0 16.1 11.9 29.4 27.4 31.7C78.4 106.8 8 190 8 288c0 47.4 30.8 72.3 56 84.7V400H256V372.7c25.2-12.5 56-37.4 56-84.7c0-37.3-10.2-72.4-25.3-104.1l-99.4 99.4c-6.2 6.2-16.4 6.2-22.6 0s-6.2-16.4 0-22.6L270.8 154.6c-23.2-38.1-51.8-69.5-74.2-90.9C212.1 61.4 224 48.1 224 32c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32H128zM48 432L6.6 473.4c-4.2 4.2-6.6 10-6.6 16C0 501.9 10.1 512 22.6 512H297.4c12.5 0 22.6-10.1 22.6-22.6c0-6-2.4-11.8-6.6-16L272 432H48z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
`;
const renderKnight = (color) => `
  <div class="piece" data-piece="knight" data-color="${color}">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
      <path d="M96 48L82.7 61.3C70.7 73.3 64 89.5 64 106.5V238.9c0 10.7 5.3 20.7 14.2 26.6l10.6 7c14.3 9.6 32.7 10.7 48.1 3l3.2-1.6c2.6-1.3 5-2.8 7.3-4.5l49.4-37c6.6-5 15.7-5 22.3 0c10.2 7.7 9.9 23.1-.7 30.3L90.4 350C73.9 361.3 64 380 64 400H384l28.9-159c2.1-11.3 3.1-22.8 3.1-34.3V192C416 86 330 0 224 0H83.8C72.9 0 64 8.9 64 19.8c0 7.5 4.2 14.3 10.9 17.7L96 48zm24 68a20 20 0 1 1 40 0 20 20 0 1 1 -40 0zM22.6 473.4c-4.2 4.2-6.6 10-6.6 16C16 501.9 26.1 512 38.6 512H409.4c12.5 0 22.6-10.1 22.6-22.6c0-6-2.4-11.8-6.6-16L384 432H64L22.6 473.4z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
`;
const renderPawn = (color) => `
  <div class="piece" data-piece="pawn" data-color="${color}">
    <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
      <path d="M215.5 224c29.2-18.4 48.5-50.9 48.5-88c0-57.4-46.6-104-104-104S56 78.6 56 136c0 37.1 19.4 69.6 48.5 88H96c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32c0 16.5 12.5 30 28.5 31.8L80 400H240L227.5 287.8c16-1.8 28.5-15.3 28.5-31.8c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32h-8.5zM22.6 473.4c-4.2 4.2-6.6 10-6.6 16C16 501.9 26.1 512 38.6 512H281.4c12.5 0 22.6-10.1 22.6-22.6c0-6-2.4-11.8-6.6-16L256 432H64L22.6 473.4z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
`;

const renderPiece = (piece, color) => {
  switch (piece) {
    case 'king'   : return renderKing(color);
    case 'queen'  : return renderQueen(color);
    case 'rook'   : return renderRook(color);
    case 'bishop' : return renderBishop(color);
    case 'knight' : return renderKnight(color);
    case 'pawn'   : return renderPawn(color);
    default       :
      throw new Error(`Cannot render unknown piece: ${piece}`);
  }
};

const startPieces = [
  renderPiece('rook'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('knight' , 'black'),
  renderPiece('bishop' , 'black'),
  renderPiece('queen'  , 'black'),
  renderPiece('king'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('bishop' , 'black'),
  renderPiece('knight' , 'black'),
  renderPiece('rook'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'black'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'black'),
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('pawn'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('rook'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('knight' , 'white'),
  renderPiece('bishop' , 'white'),
  renderPiece('queen'  , 'white'),
  renderPiece('king'   , 'white'),
  renderPiece('bishop' , 'white'),
  renderPiece('knight' , 'white'),
  renderPiece('rook'   , 'white'),
];

function createBoard() {
  startPieces.forEach((startPieces, i) => {
    const square = document.createElement('div');
    square.classList.add('square');
    const row = Math.trunc(i / 8), col = i % 8;
    square.classList.add((row ^ col) % 2 === 0 ? 'beige' : 'brown');
    square.innerHTML = startPieces;
    square.setAttribute('sqaure-id', i);
    gameBoard.append(square);
  });
}

createBoard();
```

```css
#gameboard {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.square svg {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.beige {
  background-color: rgb(110, 110, 98);
}

.brown {
  background-color: rgb(169, 43, 43);
}

.piece {
  width: 100px;
}

.piece[data-color="white"] > svg { fill: #fcc; }
.piece[data-color="black"] > svg { fill: #200; }
```

```html
<div id="gameboard"></div>
<p>It is <span id="player"></span>go.</p>
<p id="info-display"></p>
```